# Cannot assign value to getter only IDictionary property in ObjectInitializer

Tags: c#

Why cannot I assign a manually created object to a readonly `IDictionary` property using an Object initializer in the following code? What is the difference between the syntax that works and the ones the compiler is rejecting? This is C# 8. .Net core 3.1 under Windows 10

```
class Container
    {
        public IDictionary<string,string> Dict { get; }
    }
    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var c1 = new Container()
            {
                Dict = //no problem
                {
                    {"key", "value"}
                }
            };

            //assigning a Dictionary<string,string> instance to the type of the Dict property is OK 
            IDictionary<string, string> manual = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            manual["key"] = "value";

            var c2 = new Container()
            {
                //    Program.cs(31, 17): [CS0200] Property or indexer 'Container.Dict' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
                Dict = manual
            };

            var c3 = new Container()
            {
                //  Program.cs(37, 17): [CS0200] Property or indexer 'Container.Dict' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
                Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            };
            
        }
    }
```

**Update:** I'll keep the question despite the fact that the linked question at the top provides an indirect answer, since the answers here highlight useful points.

I can see that my confusion stems from the assumption that the syntax that works is an assignment. It is not. It is actually a series of `Add` calls to an IEnumerable property (which must be non-null at the time of the call). Assignment would not work because object initializer is not a replacement for the constructor, the code within the object initialization block is subject to access control rules of the public interface of the type.

Just in case someone ends up here after a google search...

Comment: I don't see `readonly` anywhere in the code you've posted.

Comment: @IanKemp It only defines `get` not `set`.

Comment: That's not the same as `readonly`.

Comment: @IanKemp The `readonly` keyword only applies to fields. The property `Dict` is read-only i.e. it can only be set on construction.

Comment: No, but it is the same as read only. You're the only one who brought up the `readonly` keyword in an attempt to be pedantic.

Comment: @xandermonkey, this is not a `private set`, it's still illegal to set it from within the class, except during the constructor. This is a `get`-only property.

Comment: @Blindy sure but the underlying problem and explanation are the same.

Comment: I edited the question, better be specific when we can be :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Dict` property has no setter - it cannot be set, therefore using an assignment statement `= someDict` fails compilation.

When you "set" it in the first example, you're not actually setting a new value to the property. What the code `= {{"key", "value"}}` really does is calls the underlying public `Add` methods on the dictionary.

It's the same thing as doing this:

```cs
var c1 = new Container();
c1.Dict.Add("key", "value");
```

Answer (score 2):

A getter only property, like your `Container.Dict`, obviously still has to be set sometime, so it's more of a "getter-only, except during construction".

However the pattern you're using is not part of the `Container`'s constructor, so it can't write to it -- it's essentially too late. This is why you should provide a correct constructor, or even better write your class like this:

```
class Container
{
    public IDictionary<string,string> Dict { get; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

The pattern you are using that "works" (in quotes) is:

```
        var c1 = new Container()
        {
            Dict = //no problem
            {
                {"key", "value"}
            }
        };
```

Which translates to:

```
var c1 = new Container();
c1.Dict.Add("key", "value");
```

Which compiles, sure, but it'll crash with a null reference exception. If you rewrite the container class as I said above it'll fully work for you.

Comment: thanks, good catch with the null property